# How do I rewrite the main page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

if there is no index file in the folder how do i rewrite an index file from another folder...so for example the main site has two folders like this

```
main_folder/no index.php
folder1/index.php
folder2/index.php
```

what do i have to put in the rewrite rule to make the main page show the index for folder1/index.php

**EDIT**

got it working with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Did you encounter problems?

Comment: i tried this and this RewriteRule ^$ /folder1/index.php [L]
but i think i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#in the .htaccess file where there is no exit or in root
Options Indexes #if still fails delete this line
DirectoryIndex /folder1/index.php
```

Not sure though

edit: for sub levels maybe adding this solves.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i tried that and got ....Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: "Options Indexes" <- try like this (remove - sign on first line). If that also fails, retry with deleting that line. Edit: deleting the line should work: http://davidwalsh.name/directory-index-homepage-htaccess

Comment: that works great but when i visit the url site.com/folder1 i still need the same site and i dont have that

Comment: Maybe adding this solves?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

do you just want a redirect?

```
Redirect 301 / /folder1/index.php
```